# iOS app Push Notification not showing in Beta Tester user's device

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, testflight

We built an iOS app using Swift 4.x in Xcode 10.1. The app get push notification in my development iPhone 6 very well from other devices.

We published the app to TestFlight for beta testers. They install the app from TestFlight and get prompt to allow Notification. All went well. When they send me a message, I get Push Notification without any problem in my iPhone 6. But when I send them, no notification pops up on their screen.

Is it something related to code signing? Or what else I should check for.

[image]

Your suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to replace the Push certificate on your Push API server. APNS Distribution certificate is to be used in your case.

Comment: You need to upload your APNS distribution certificate in the console (May be, you have only uploaded development certificate).

Comment: Did you mean console by iTunesConnect @MahendraThotakura? If yes, then how. I did download the APNS distribution certificate from iTunesConnect and install it in my Mac and found in Keychain. What else you meant by that please?

Comment: Do you have any reference link @DhavalBhimani please?

Comment: you need to export that certificates from keychain as a .p12 Or .pem file and add it to server API( API which you are using to send push notification). and you will need to set push notification mode in server API to release mode to get push notification in testflight build.

Comment: No! I'm not referring to iTunesConnect @SiddiquiNoor. Which push notification server you are using (Firebase/GCM/ any different)? You have to upload APNS "p12 " certificate of distribution to the console.

Comment: you can export certificates of push by following this link: https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/generate-apns-certificate-for-ios-push-notifications-85e4a917d522

Comment: All of you were right. @DhavalBhimani it works perfectly as you mentioned in your first comment. You can post it like an answer for upcoming viewers. Or I can make it for you too.

Comment: thanks, glad it worked, let me add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the Push certificate on your Push API server. APNS Distribution certificate is to be used in your case.

for that,
you need to export that certificates from keychain as a .p12 Or .pem file and add it to server API( API which you are using to send push notification). and you will need to set push notification mode in server API to release mode to get push notification in testflight build.

you can export certificates of push by following steps in this link:
https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/generate-apns-certificate-for-ios-push-notifications-85e4a917d522